# Unable to detect what div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want every li tag to show the a's clicked href content below that li tag in a div. For example, I have a structure like this:

```
<ul id="ids">
<li class="res"><a class="item">item1</a></li>
<li class="res"><a class="item">item2</a></li>
<li class="res"><a class="item">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Dynamically if a's href is clicked, accordingly a function that shows the div `<div class="testing"><h3>showing item1 here</h3></div>` outside the `<a>` tag needs to be shown. That function could take time so until then Loading... needs to be shown. But I am unable to detect where the user has clicked as class names are the same. Once loading is done, loading should be hidden.

So far I have this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
$(this).append('Loading');

//function code here

$(this).append('<div class="testing"><h3>showing item1 here</h3></div>');
});
```

Also, the function appends 1 div tag with class 'mydiv', that needs to be hidden. But again, since class names that get appended to every `<li>` is the same, I don't know where the click has taken place to detect it.

to summarise:

- show a list of elements which has anchor tag
- click on every element should show the content of the click in a div under that anchor tag
- content of anchor tag can take 2 seconds so until then user should see "loading". Once it loads, loading should be hidden

Comment: You try to append a `div` in a `a` which is not acceptable html, you can't have a `block` element in `inline` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `$.after()` or `$.insertAfter()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var aTag = $(this);
  if (aTag.siblings('.testing, .loader').length === 0) { //it's not loaded or loading
    var loader = $('<div class="loader">Loading</div>');
    loader.insertAfter(aTag);
    //function code here

    loader.remove();
    aTag.after('<div class="testing"><h3>showing ' + aTag.html() + ' here</h3></div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ids">
  <li class="res"><a class="item">item1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="res"><a class="item">item2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="res"><a class="item">item3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to avoid multiple loadings check if it exists before:

```
if(aTag.siblings('.testing, .loader').length === 0){ //it's not loaded or loading

}
```

Comment: But how do I detect that if <div class="testing" is already added then dont append again as for me right now, it just keeps appending.

Comment: @fscore, you need to check if the elements exist before loading again. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the href attribute using `$(this).  This should work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $(this).append('Loading');
  $(this).append('<div class="testing"><h3>showing ' + href + ' here</h3></div>');
});
```

Also, the code above will append the div inside the a tag.  You probably want to put it somewhere else using something like

```
 $("#messageDiv").html('<div class="testing"><h3>showing ' + href + ' here</h3></div>');
```

To hide the loading message, you can wrap that in a span

```
 $(this).append('<span class="loadingspan">Loading</span>');
```

Then in the code that runs when the load is complete, you can use

```
$('.loadingspan').hide();
```

Comment: once the div loads, loading needs to be hidden

Comment: I want div class testing outside <a> tag. can you show me a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/91a8Losa/.  I've added a psuedo event loaded section to illustrate how to hide what you've just loaded.

Comment: wouldnt  $(this).append('<span class="loadingspan">Loading</span>'); be inside a tag

Comment: Yes.  That's what you have now.  I suggested creating a div like `<div id="messagediv"></div>` and putting your messages in there.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle.  This of course would only work if the user clicks one link at a time and waits patiently, which we know won't happen.  You could do something like this in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72f12ck3/2/